# 400 Bad Request - Invalid Hostname when making nancy self hosted Web API calls locally

Tags: c#, owin, nancy

I'm self hosing a website in a windows service via nancy/owin. The site gets hosted fine, and I can hit the site in a browser both locally and from another machine. All calls to my Web API endpoints work just fine when interacting with the site.

The problem comes when trying to hit the Web API endpoints locally via another application - except when I connect with the IP address. For instance, I have a console application where I am making a simple GET request. If I run the app locally connecting with the machine name (base name or fully qualified) or localhost, I get 400 Bad Request - Invalid Hostname. If I do that same request using the IP address, it works fine. On the other hand, if I run the console app on another machine on the same domain, it will work regardless of which host name I use. Firewalls are off on both machines. What could be causing this?

Here is the code I am using to register my urls:

```
public void Start(int port = 1234)
{
    // Get URIS with port num
    var uris = GetUriParams(port);

    // Add Host URLs
    var startOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions();
    foreach (var uri in uris)
        startOptions.Urls.Add(uri.ToString());

    // Start OWIN
    this._owinApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>(startOptions);
}

private static Uri[] GetUriParams(int port)
{
    var uriParams = new List<Uri>();
    string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();

    // Host name URI
    string hostNameUri = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", Dns.GetHostName(), port);
    uriParams.Add(new Uri(hostNameUri));

    // Host address URI(s)
    var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
    foreach (var ipAddress in hostEntry.AddressList)
    {
        if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)  // IPv4 addresses only
        {
            var addrBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
            string hostAddressUri = string.Format("http://{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}:{4}", addrBytes[0], addrBytes[1], addrBytes[2], addrBytes[3], port);
            uriParams.Add(new Uri(hostAddressUri));
        }
    }

    // Localhost URI
    uriParams.Add(new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}", port)));
    return uriParams.ToArray();
}
```

And here is the web request I am making in my console app:

```
var getDataFormatString = "http://{0}:{1}/API/MyService/GetData";
var fqdn = "mymachine";
var address = string.Format(getDataFormatString, fqdn, 1234);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(address));
request.Method = "GET";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nancy may have changed since you posted this question, but in my experience this has to do with the `HostConfiguration.RewriteLocalhost` setting. When I set this to `false` I get the same behavior you see.

When `HostConfiguration.RewriteLocalhost=true`, then I also need to create a URL reservation using `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:port user=<appropriate-user>`